# Can't select added tr by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I add table and it's raws by jQuery when find result in database,and remove table when don't find anything.It works correctly.

```
$("#AdminSearch").bind("change keyup", function() { 
       var url = "http://localhost/PmMusic/index.php/admin/ajax/admin_search/"+$("#AdminSearch").val();
        $.getJSON(url,function(data){
            if (data.length == 0)
            {
                $("#AutoSearch").hide(1000);
                $("#AutoSearchTable").remove();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#AutoSearchTable").remove();
                $("#AutoSearch").append('<table id="AutoSearchTable">');
                for(var i = 0;i < data.length && i < 5;i++)
                    {
                     $("#AutoSearchTable").append('<tr><td id="TableSearchTR'+i+'" value="'+data[i]+'">'+data[i]+'</td></tr>');
                    }
                $("#AutoSearch").append('</table>');
                $("#AutoSearch").show(1000);    
            }
        });

    });
```

but when I wanna select tr by following code

```
    $('tr').click(function(){
        alert("Hi");
    });
```

When I click on other table tr in page it works,but it can't select tr which added by upper code).
where is the problem?

Comment: You don't need `$("#AutoSearch").append('</table>');` because the first append will add an entire table element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're binding with .click, which only applies to elements already in the page.

Change your code to

```
$('tr').live('click', function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Comment: .delegate() would give better performance because it would not have to traverse the entire DOM

Comment: @ShaneBlake As far as I know, the only difference is that delegate forces you to give a context to it. `.live` with a context have similar performance. I guess (no proof), that in this particular case, that there won't be much difference, as jQuery will use native `getElementsByTagName`, which is fast.

Comment: With .live() the context is the top of the DOM, so there could be quite a bit of difference, actually...

Comment: I know, but you can specify the context: `$('tr', context).live(handler);`, or `$('#contextId tr').live(handler);`. In both cases, they'll have performance similar to delegate's.

Comment: In the OP example, where (looks like) there's only one table and all trs in the page will be bounded, there won't be a difference in giving a context

Comment: In the OP example, performance may be similar, but you cannot change the context of `.live()`.  It is always attached to the root of the DOM as per the jquery docs :  `The handler passed to .live() is never bound to an element; instead, .live() binds a special handler to the root of the DOM tree.`

Comment: From jQuery docs: `* As of jQuery 1.4, event bubbling can optionally stop at a DOM element "context".`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach click events to dynamically-created elements.

```
$("#AdminSearch").delegate("tr","click",function() {
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the TR is not there when your .click() function is added, then it won't have a click event attached.  You should look at using the .delegate() function instead.

Answer (score 0):

[click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) will only work for elements already in the DOM. If you're loading in some content w/ ajax then I would suggest [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$('tr').live('click', function() {
  alert("Hi");
});
```